# Unable to get data from object

Tags: javascript

newbie here.
i have made an object like this

```
var myMovie1=
        {

            title:'Plan 9 from Outer Space',
            genre:'Classic',
            rating:3,
            showTimes:[6,8,11]

        };


        var myMovie2=
        {

            title:'Rush',
            genre:'Action',
            rating:5,
            showTimes:[3,6,14]

        };
```

Now created functions to check current time and movie alerts like this

```
// function to get date and time
var now =new Date().getHours();


function letsSeeMovie(myMovieSelected){
    for (var i = 0; i < myMovieSelected.showTimes.length; i++) {
        var showTime=myMovieSelected.showTimes[i];

        if (now<showTime) {
            return "The next moive starts at " + showTime + "am";
        }
        else
        {
            return "sorry you just missed it"
        }

    }
}
var okcanWeSeeit=letsSeeMovie(myMovie2);
document.write(okcanWeSeeit);
```

But somehow in the moive object it only displays "**sorry missed i**t".
it dosent **reach 11* and show the next playing time.
Where i am doing it wrong?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return after iterating all the myMovieSelected

```
function letsSeeMovie(myMovieSelected){
    for (var i = 0; i < myMovieSelected.showTimes.length; i++) {
        var showTime=myMovieSelected.showTimes[i];
        console.log(showTime)
        if (now<showTime) {
            return "The next moive starts at " + showTime + "am";
        }

    }

    return "u miss it"
}
```

What you did just now is, you iterate the first element, if it doesnt match you already break the loop

Answer (score 1):

You have a return statement in your cycle. It means, if the first movie is missed, it's not checking the other showtimes. Consider removing return statement from the "you missed it" clause.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you have passed the **myMovie2** variable which doesn't have 11 as the data. Also you have done only one check, that is in the if condition you are writing the return statement for only one condition. Which is being pointed out by everyone.